# Flutter horizontal and vertical list view

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

This is my sample horizontal and vertical listview. In my list view red and yellow parts are the horizontal scrollable listview. i need to scroll all the red and yellow rows horizontally at same time when a yellow or red row scroll

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("widget.title"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) =>
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height:40,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Card(
                          child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 30,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text("let item upto Tags ")),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: 20,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                controller: _1scrollController,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 30,
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    child: Text("item $index"),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [

                      for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Card(
                              child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 30,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  child: Text("let item upto Tags ")),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: 20,
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    controller: _2scrollController,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Container(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 30,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        child: Text("item $index"),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],

                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

UI SS

[image]

Comment: Can you include your current code snippet

Comment: Do you want combine scroll on red items on independent

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I need scroll horizontally red and yellow rows in same time and all red items should scroll same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Just found  [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller) by google.

```dart
  LinkedScrollControllerGroup controllerGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
  late final headerController = controllerGroup.addAndGet();
  late final childrenController = controllerGroup.addAndGet();
```

There is some issue on your snippet , And I've redesign the snippet

```dart
class SGGA extends StatefulWidget {
  SGGA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SGGA> createState() => _SGGAState();
}

class _SGGAState extends State<SGGA> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  LinkedScrollControllerGroup controllerGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
  late final headerController = controllerGroup.addAndGet();
  late final childrenController = controllerGroup.addAndGet();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("widget.title"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: 40,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: constraints.maxWidth * .4 - 16, //padding rem
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Text("Info tag x"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: headerController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text("data $i"),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    // height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            width: constraints.maxWidth * .4,
                            // height: constraints.maxHeight,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      child: Text("Info tag $i"),
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ],
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth * .6,
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            controller: childrenController,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 40,
                                      color: Colors.purple,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: 40,
                                                height: 40,
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                child: Text("data $i"),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try to listen 1st controller and according to changes scroll the inner one.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _1scrollController.addListener(() {
      _2scrollController.jumpTo(_1scrollController.offset);
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks but is works only for when yellow row sroll.still red rows are independently scrolling

Comment: You also like to scroll top yellow from red ?

Comment: Yes. Actually thisa like a table,yellow row tike table headers

Comment: Are you trying to create a table with Text

Comment: its should list view which can scroll vertically and horizontally

Comment: Thank you very much.this is working very well, highly appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

If both list are scrolling at same time you can do something like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 40,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    height: 60,
                    width: 40,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  );
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 40,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    height: 60,
                    width: 40,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks,But can’t use this because needs to scroll red and blue line vertically also